# Submit button of the form in Asp.net core mvc Stopped Working Suddenly after using the javascript to create the dynamic DOM

Tags: javascript, html, .net, razor, .net-core

Below is my code i am not knowing Why my Form Submit button stopped working suddenly.please some one guide me with the solution.

I have verified the name of the Controller , Asp-action name and all other model fields they all are correct but still my form is not getting submit.

before i added a javascript form was submitting properly ,i have verified it multiple times it was absolutely flawless. later when added javascript it stopped working ,i tried commenting js and run still it is not working i am unable to figure what is the issue.

```
@model InventoryProject.Models.BillInfoModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddBillToDb";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Add BillInfo</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" asp-controller="BillInfo" asp-action="AddBillToDb" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BillNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BillNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BillNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UploadBill" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UploadBill" accept="image/*" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UploadBill" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BillDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BillDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BillDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PurchasedBy" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PurchasedBy" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PurchasedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ApprovedBy" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ApprovedBy" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ApprovedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalCenter">
                    Add Items
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="ModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Item</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="NextItem" class="modal-body">
                                <partial name="_AddItemPartial" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" onclick="addRow()" class="btn btn-secondary">Add Item</button>
                                <button type="button" onclick="duplicate()" class="btn btn-secondary">Clear</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->

            <div class="form-group">
                <h2>List of Items You Added</h2>
                <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                SerialNumber
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                ItemName
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Category
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                PurchaseDate
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                PurchaseHours
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                UserGroup
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                AssignedTo
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                History
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                BillInfo
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Status
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                RemoveItem
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Bill" formaction="AddBillToDb" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="BillIndex">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementById('NextItem');

    function duplicate() {
        original.innerHTML = document.getElementById('NextItem').innerHTML
    };

    function productDelete(ctl) {
        $(ctl).parents("tr").remove();
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow() {
        "use strict";

        var table = document.getElementById("table");

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        console.log(row);
        var td1 = document.createElement("td");
        var td2 = document.createElement("td");
        var td3 = document.createElement("td");
        var td4 = document.createElement("td");
        var td5 = document.createElement("td");
        var td6 = document.createElement("td");
        var td7 = document.createElement("td");
        var td8 = document.createElement("td");
        var td9 = document.createElement("td");
        var td0 = document.createElement("td");
        var td11 = document.createElement("td")

        td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("SerialNumber").value;
        td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("ItemName").value;
        td3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Category").value;
        td4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("PurchaseDate").value;
        td5.innerHTML = document.getElementById("PurchaseHours").value;
        td0.innerHTML = document.getElementById("UserGroup").value;
        td6.innerHTML = document.getElementById("AssignedTo").value;
        td7.innerHTML = document.getElementById("History").value;
        td8.innerHTML = document.getElementById("BillInfo").value;
        td9.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Status").value;
        td11.innerHTML = "<button type='button' " +
            "onclick='productDelete(this);' " +
            "class='btn btn-warning'>" + "X" + "</button>"

        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
        row.appendChild(td3);
        row.appendChild(td4);
        row.appendChild(td5);
        row.appendChild(td0);
        row.appendChild(td6);
        row.appendChild(td7);
        row.appendChild(td8);
        row.appendChild(td9);
        row.appendChild(td11)

        table.children[0].appendChild(row);
    };
```

Comment: So the `submit` button now does absolutely nothing when clicked? If you look in the console are you seeing errors when the page loads or when buttons are clicked?

Comment: No i don't see Any errors in console